# I can't figure out why I'm getting StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, quicksort

So I'm attempting to quicksort a singly linked list. Since I can't traverse backward like the traditional quicksort, I made it traverse forward to partition the list... But, if anyone could tell me where I'm getting this StackOverflowError it would really be appreciated.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quickSort(MyNode<E> first, MyNode<E> last) {
    if(first != last) {
        MyNode<E> pivot = first;
        MyNode<E> currentNode = first.next;
        MyNode<E> previousNode = first;

        while(currentNode.next != last && currentNode.next != null) {
            if (currentNode.element.compareTo(pivot.element) < 0) {
                MyNode<E> temp = new MyNode<E>(currentNode.element);
                previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
                temp.next = first;
                first = currentNode;
            }
            previousNode = previousNode.next;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        quickSort(first, pivot);
        quickSort(pivot, last);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
So thanks to your guys help I am a little bit closer I think... But I am still stuck. I have changed my code based on suggestions. But now it is just not sorting correctly.. The issue is when I try to move current to the front of the list... It seems to disconnect it from the list. So, when I print out the list all I get back is the pivot and the values greater than the pivot.. All of the lesser than elements have disappeared..

```
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quickSort(MyNode<E> first, MyNode<E> last) {
    if(first != last && first != null) {
        E pivot = first.element;
        MyNode<E> current = first.next;
        MyNode<E> previous = first;


        while(previous != last && current != null) {
            if (current.element.compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                previous.next = current.next;
                first = current;
                first.next = previous;
                current = previous.next;
            }
            else {
                previous = previous.next;
                current = current.next;
            }
            //recursive calls will go here... Just want to get the logic right first
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How big is the List you are trying to sort?  Method stack can have only so many methods stacked on top of eachother...If it works for a small list but not for a big list then the problem is that you are putting to many method calls on a stack...It's not really a problem just a constraint of Java...

Comment: If it doesn't work for even a small list then you have another problem you probably don't have a terminating case where the recursion eventually stops (never ending loop except with recursion)...

Comment: You seem to insert new nodes while sorting, why? You should just swap nodes if needed.

Comment: Btw, IIRC you should call the recursive calls before the loop and not after it. Also AFAIK the pivot element should be the element in the middle and not the first one.

Comment: Well, the idea I had for the loop was so that it could get the pivot element in the middle. The loop is supposed to put elements less than the pivot to the left of it and elements greater than stay to the right of it.

Comment: But pivot is the first element....

Comment: @user3602199 you're right, I had an error in my memory ;) loop first, then recursion - but do it correctly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem (the StackOverflowError you're getting) is, that you don't change `pivot` and hence the recursive call to `quickSort(pivot, last);` will be the same as `quickSort(first, last);` and thus `first != last` will always be true for any list of size > 1.

You should first set `pivot` to the middle element, then sort elements according to being greater or smaller than the pivot and then call quicksort recursively for the sublists. Here though, you shouldn't pass pivot twice, otherwise you'd still get a stack overflow.

Assume you end up with a sublist of only two elements and you pick one as the pivot. One recursive call would do nothing since `first = last` but the other would essentially be `quicksort(first, last)`, would select the same pivot and repeat with the very same sublist.

So either pass `pivot +/- 1` to one of the recursive calls (since it's a linked list I'd suggest `quicksort(pivot.next, last)` ) or check whether the sublist has more than 2 elements before doing the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance... you are looping quickSort too many times and therefor you get that error.

example

```
private void countUp(int x){
    System.out.println(x);
    countUp(++x);
}
```

this will count about 10541 times for me... before throwing that error.

With that in mind... you might have an infinite loop somewhere OR your array are too large.